# writing serial port driver in linux to use serial registers in mini 2440

Tags: linux, serialization, embedded, embedded-linux

I have a Mini-2440 board that has 3 serial channels. I'm using Linux as the embedded RTOS. I would like to use the serial channel registers to transmit and receive messages. I'm new to embedded Linux. The only example code on the web I could find used file descriptors to read and write to port. Is it possible to use the serial channel registers on Mini-2440 to transmit and receive serial messages?

Comment: *"I'm using Linux as the embedded RTOS"* -- Linux is not a *realtime* OS.  *"example code on the web I could find used file descriptors to read and write to port"* -- That's the user API using system calls to the OS. *"Is it possible to use the serial channel registers..."* -- Yes but access to port registers should be accessed only by kernel device drivers, not user code.  *"I'm new to embedded Linux"* -- Seems like you're new to using an operating system too.

Comment: Actually, Linux has several RT forks.  Not anywhere near as good as something like QNX, but they do exist.  Burnable, embeddable, RT-capable.  Even Wind River went down this road.  Not even close to my first choice for hard RT (but if you pay me enough, I'll deal).

Comment: The Linux device driver for the serial ports on the Mini 2440 is [drivers/tty/serial/samsung.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/samsung.c).